# What to pass to the Intent constructor to have a geric method?

Tags: android, generics, android-intent

I'm trying to create a method that can be reused each time I want to go to the MainActivity:

```
public void goToMainActivity(Activity activity) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    activity.startActivity(intent);
    activity.finish();
}
```

I have tried to change `UserActivity.this` that work for that particular activity into `activity.getClass()` but it doesn't work. What should I pass as the first parameter to the Intent constructor?

Comment: Just `activity`.

Comment: Are serious? It worked! Never thought about this. Thank you so much Mike!!!